# Why wont my video render?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I am using blender for minor video editing. I added my movie using the sequencer, and adjusted the start and end frames to trim down the length. When I hit animate or render the progress bar in the top right flashes 0% and then goes away. The resulting file in my blender output directory is a 0:00:00 mp4 file.

edit: uploaded userpref.blend
[image]

Comment: Hmm...do you think you could include a screenshot or .blend file? That would help a lot!

Comment: Just as JEE said, you should provide more information. Just upload your blend file onto https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com.

Comment: added userpref.blend